# JQuery: push dynamically allocated objects of different lengths to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, dynamic

The 'arr' array is created dynamically based upon user input, so its contents change in the functioning version. The user input can be any length, so may not necessarily contain 5 words. The problem is that I am unsure how to create the `words` object dynamically with a varying number of children in order to push it to the correct member of `combos`.

```js
var arr = [
  [
    ["this", 0],
    ["is", 1],
    ["a", 2],
    ["complete", 3],
    ["sentence", 4],
    ["with", 5],
    ["index", 6],
    ["data", 7]
  ]
];

var partOne = {
  two: [],
  three: [],
  four: [],
  five: []
}

var len = arr.length;

var print = [];

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var lenGr = arr[i].length;
  for (var j = 0; j < lenGr - 1; j++) {
    partOne.two.push({
      "words": {
        "word1": arr[i][j],
        "word2": arr[i][j + 1]
      }
    });
  }
  for (j = 0; j < lenGr - 2; j++) {
    partOne.three.push({
      "words": {
        "word1": arr[i][j],
        "word2": arr[i][j + 1],
        "word3": arr[i][j + 2]
      }
    });
  }
  for (j = 0; j < lenGr - 3; j++) {
    partOne.four.push({
      "words": {
        "word1": arr[i][j],
        "word2": arr[i][j + 1],
        "word3": arr[i][j + 2],
        "word4": arr[i][j + 3]
      }
    });
  }
  for (j = 0; j < lenGr - 4; j++) {
    partOne.five.push({
      "words": {
        "word1": arr[i][j],
        "word2": arr[i][j + 1],
        "word3": arr[i][j + 2],
        "word4": arr[i][j + 3],
        "word5": arr[i][j + 4]
      }
    });
  }
}

console.log("Current solution : ");
console.log(partOne);

var partTwo = {
  two: [],
  three: [],
  four: [],
  five: []
};
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var lenGr = arr[i].length;
  $.each(partTwo, function(ind, val) {
    for (var j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < lenGr - j; k++) {
        // Populate 'partTwo' dynamically, in the same format as partOne.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is that your actual array definition? Its syntax is completely broken.

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: Your first `var arr = [ 0 = [ 0 = ["this", 0], 1 = ["is", 1], 2 = ["a", 2], 3 = ["complete", 3], 4 = ["sentence", 4], 5 = ["with", 5], 6 = ["index", 6], 7 = ["data", 7] ] ];` has invalid syntax

Comment: Perhaps he meant `var arr = [
  [
    ["this", 0],
    ["is", 1],
    ["a", 2],
    ["complete", 3],
    ["sentence", 4],
    ["with", 5],
    ["index", 6],
    ["data", 7]
  ]
];`

Comment: @mplungjan that is what i thought as well (though OP must clarify), but it is not clear what he wants to transform it into.

Comment: Yes that is correct. My mistake. As the array members are generated dynamically I had just copied over the format from the code inspector on my browser. The array in my code is fully functioning.

Comment: I have added a code snippet which logs my current solution in the console. The `console.log` statement is followed by my current progress with a dynamic solution, as well as a comment explaining my desired outcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply provided a switch statement which monitors `j` in order to determine the number of array members counted during that iteration, then repeated the original code to push the new objects into `partTwo`. There may be a more elegant solution.

```js
var arr = [
  [
    ["this", 0],
    ["is", 1],
    ["a", 2],
    ["complete", 3],
    ["sentence", 4],
    ["with", 5],
    ["index", 6],
    ["data", 7]
  ]
];

var partTwo = {
  two: [],
  three: [],
  four: [],
  five: []
};

var len = arr.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var lenGr = arr[i].length;
  for (var j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < lenGr - j; k++) {
      switch (j) {
        case 1:
          partTwo.two.push({
            "words": {
              "word1": arr[i][k],
              "word2": arr[i][k + 1]
            }
          });
          break;
        case 2:
          partTwo.three.push({
            "words": {
              "word1": arr[i][k],
              "word2": arr[i][k + 1],
              "word3": arr[i][k + 2]
            }
          });
          break;
        case 3:
          partTwo.four.push({
            "words": {
              "word1": arr[i][k],
              "word2": arr[i][k + 1],
              "word3": arr[i][k + 2],
              "word4": arr[i][k + 3]
            }
          });
          break;
        case 4:
          partTwo.five.push({
            "words": {
              "word1": arr[i][k],
              "word2": arr[i][k + 1],
              "word3": arr[i][k + 2],
              "word4": arr[i][k + 3],
              "word5": arr[i][k + 4]
            }
          });
          break;
        default:
          console.log("Error with j switch.");
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(partTwo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```